# Complex number locus on Argand Plane

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

If the point $z$ in the complex plane describes a circle with radius $2$ with centre at the origin then the point $z+\frac{1}{z}$ describe...

Options

A Circle

A parabola

an ellipse

a hyperbola

What I did... Did some elementary manipulations on the given term and conditions but couldn't really equate my manipulations to anything.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Putting $z=2e^{it}$ gives the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the transformed
shape as $x=(5/2)\cos t$ and $y=(3/2)\sin t$. These parametrise the ellipse
$$\frac{x^2}{(5/2)^2}+\frac{y^2}{(3/2)^2}=1.$$